# How to do an SQL Server Recursive CTE

Tags: sql-server

I have a table where each record contains a unique Numeric id and 2 parent ids (mother, father). I would like to find a way to list the parents(2), grandparents(4), great grandparents(8) and so on down to a specified level. Before I give up on pure SQL and do it in Python, can anyone tell me a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like below, where once you pass child numericId, you get corresponding parents and from there, recursively you get higher levels.

You can filter the levels using parentlevel filter.

```sql
DECLARE @childNumericId AS INT
;WITH CTE_Ancestory AS (
    SELECT numericId AS child, ParentId1 as father, parentId2 as mother, 1 as parentlevel 
    FROM tableName
    WHERE numericId = @childNumericId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.NumericId AS child, t.ParentId1 as father, t.parentId2 as mother, c.parentlevel + 1 AS parentLevel
    FROM tableName AS t
    INNER JOIN CTE_Ancestory AS c ON t.numericId IN (c.father, c.mother) 
)
SELECT *
from CTE_Ancestory
Where parentlevel < 4 -- number of levels you need
```

Comment: @DaleK, Thanks for your extra validation. Sorry about that. It is not tested code. I just provided pseudo code. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I removed the extra cte_ in the from line.

Comment: @ihf, glad it worked. thanks for your extra eye on this. I have updated my pseudocode